# same js script does not work on different html pages

Tags: javascript, html

first page of mine located in root folder of the project has name start.html and contains this `<script>` nodes:

```
  <script src='https://code.s3.yandex.net/web-code/smoothly.js'></script>
  <script src="./core/mainStrings.js"></script>
  <script src="./chapters/lore/lorescript.js"></script>
```

this page works completely fine.
second page of mine has name makeCharacter.html and contains this `<script>` nodes:

```
  <script src='https://code.s3.yandex.net/web-code/smoothly.js'></script>
  <script src="./core/mainStrings.js"></script>
  <script src="./chapters/makeCharacter/characterScript.js"></script>
```

i use mainStrings.js to contain all the main data from the input buttons of the pages and using it on other pages. when i try to execute characterScript.js it goes out with undefined parameters error. it does not have parameters that is holded in mainStrings.js. i think that mainStrings is not loading on the page and have no clue why.

[error when code executing is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQfAB.png)

[structure of files is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxugF.png)

Comment: Can you post your folder structure? I sounds like `makeCharacter.html` isn't in your root folder?

Comment: Usually we use DOMContentLoaded event to wait that everything, including all the scripts in script tags are loaded before doing anything with the scripts.

Comment: `goes out with undefined parameters error` Please show the exact error get instead of rephrasing it with your own words.